# Identity server 4 and angular oidc not redirecting after login is complete

Tags: angular, angular6, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am trying to learn how to implement identity server in my applications, currently I am focusing on web apps built in Angular 6.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/SPA-Authentiction-using-OpenID-Connect-Angular-CLI-and-oidc-client) by [Scott Brady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3274800/scott-brady), it's helped me out a lot. But I cant get `Identity Server` to redirect me after I have logged in.

I have stepped through the `Identity Server` `AccountController` (from the Quickstart package) and I can see the below is called but I never get redirected.

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props);
...other stuff...
return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
```

If I remove all break points and submit the form, it's like the page simply reloads. I can't work out what i'm missing.

I know the urls should excatly match or it will not work, but I've check that.

`model.ReturnUrl` is:

> /connect/authorize/callback?client_id=angular_spa&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauth-callback&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20api1&state=e47c064d2d47452d9a782e5e63b1d284&nonce=ff24e277db794ffe8fef7fc155adc05b

**Angular code**

```
export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
  return {
    authority: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    client_id: 'angular_spa',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid profile api1",
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html'
  };
}
```

**Identity server**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"myCert.pfx", "password"))
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .AddTestUsers(Users.Get())
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

    services.AddMvc();
}

internal class Resources
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource> {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource> {
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API #1")
        };
    }
}

internal class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client> {
            new Client {
                ClientId = "angular_spa",
                ClientName = "Angular 4 Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string> {"openid", "profile", "api1"},
                RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200/auth-callback"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200/"},
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200"},
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
            }
        };
    }
}

internal class Users
{
    public static List<TestUser> Get()
    {
        return new List<TestUser> {
            new TestUser {
                SubjectId = "5BE86359-073C-434B-AD2D-A3932222DABE",
                Username = "scott",
                Password = "password"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

EDIT:

running identity server and navigating to `http://localhost:5000/Account/Login` then try to login displays the same behaviour

EDIT 2:

I cloned [the identity server samples](https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer4.Samples), ran 3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication and added the user from the tutorial and I still get the same behaviour

Comment: Does the endpoint http://localhost:4200/auth-callback resolve to anything?

Comment: Also is ModelStateIsValid true in your action?

Comment: @jazza1000 I can't check local:4200/auth-callback at the moment as I am not at my machine, but  ModelStateIsValid will be true as the controller action exectues fully. I have also tried to navigate directly to identity server and login using the test user but after the controllerAction finishes the login form is simply refreshed

Comment: Can you upload an [mcve] to e.g. GitHub?

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get back to my machine (sorry for not uploading it when I added the question)

Comment: I can no longer reproduce my issue. The only thing I did "to solve it" (more accurately, make it go away) was stop the client and server, when I came back the next day and started working on it again, I logged in successfully.

It leads me to believe that it was an issue with local storage or cookies, but I can't prove it either way. These issues going away did cause new issues to surface, but they are outside the scope of this question.